# How to compare data with another table's data before deleting the record in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have this db called Enrolment where all the students will be added with batch and course. `stud_id`, `course_id`, and `batch_id` are referring to the other table with the fk.

```
 enrolment
+----------+---------+-----------+----------+
| enrol_id | stud_id | course_id | batch_id |
+----------+---------+-----------+----------+
|        1 |       1 |         2 |        1 |
|        2 |       5 |         3 |        2 |
|        3 |       4 |         5 |        3 |
+----------+---------+-----------+----------+
```

Before I delete the student record in the `student` table, i want to compare the `stud_id` in the `students` table with the `stud_id` in the `enrollment` table. If it matches, do not delete the student. Or some kind of message to say this record is linked with the enrollment table, or something.

If it matches i want to run this `$sql = "DELETE FROM students WHERE student_id = $id ";`

```
students
+---------+------------+-----------+
| stud_id | first_name | last_name |
+---------+------------+-----------+
|       1 | John       | Doe       |
|       2 | Susy       | Roberts   |
|       3 | John       | redneck   |
+---------+------------+-----------+
```

Please help!!

Comment: Use foriegn keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved using `NOT IN`

```
DELETE FROM students
WHERE student_id NOT IN (SELECT stud_id 
                    FROM enrolment) AND student_id = $id
```

It can be achieved using `NOT EXISTS`

```
DELETE FROM students
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                FROM enrolment
               WHERE stud_id = $id) AND student_id = $id
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to run a query like

```
$sql = SELECT COUNT(1) FROM enrolment WHERE stu_id = $id
```

Then check the contents for the number returned if > 0 then error.